# Documentation for "expiry" field in appmodel.json for kaizala custom action

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

I cant' seem to find the field "expiry" for appmodel.json file documented anywhere. what does it represent? I am trying to set up a Kaizala custom action poll with a specific duration.

This field can be found in the examples provided but its not included and hence not documented in the schema found at this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/actions/appmodel_schema

Answer (score 0):

expiry is an Action property used in certain Kaizala OOB Actions (such as Poll, Job, Survey). This has been defined by Action developer in their Action. You can too setup a property named 'expiry' for your Action. And accordingly, use this property in Action code to define its behavior. 
Using properties, you can set a variable for any Action instance created by the Action

Answer (score 0):

Expiry is an Action property used in certain Kaizala Out of the Box Actions (such as Poll, Job, Survey) or Custom Action Cards. This has been defined by Action developer in their Action to define the expiry duration of the actions. You can too setup a property named 'expiry' for your Action. And accordingly, use this property in Action code to define its behavior. Using properties, you can set a variable for any Action instance created by the Action.